# Inheritance from Object initializer in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am new to Javascript. I have defined an object using object initializer method.

```
var obj = { a : "A";
            b : "B";
            myFunc = function() {
                alert("Hello"):
            }
```

Now I want to create another object that will be child of `Obj`. How can I do that.

```
var obj1 = new obj();
```

is not working.

Comment: `var obj1 = Object.create(obj);`

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it the way you wanted to:

```
var obj = {
    a: "A",
    b: "B",
    myFunc: function () {
        alert("Hello");
    }
};

var obj1 = Object.create(obj)
obj1.a = 2;
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you have a syntax error with

```
myFunc = function() { ...
```

Anyway, this is how you'll want to set it up

```
function Foo() {
  this.a = "A";
  this.b = "B";
}

Foo.prototype.myFunc = function() {
  alert("hello");
};
```

Now to create your child object

```
function Bar() {
  Foo.call(this); // call parent constructor; optional
}

// setup child prototype
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

Check it out

```
var b = new Bar();

b instanceof Bar; // true
b instanceof Foo; // true

b.constructor.name; // Bar

b.myFunc; // "hello"
```